# Starting Google Cardboard VR on iOS: Which SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

I want to develop a simple VR environment on iOS in order to play around with different interaction forms using Cardboard VR. This might include the need to access iPhones camera and microphone.

This is my very first experience with VR. On [Google VR page](https://developers.google.com/vr/cardboard/overview) there is an SDK for Unity and an SDK for iOS. Which path should I go?

I know that I can create a Unity application and deploy it on iOS. But is it possible then easily change/customise the generated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Unity then go for the Unity SDK. The iOS SDK is for developing natively in iOS.

When you build for iOS using Unity, Unity will generate an XCode project which you can then run. A few classes of this project will be readable (such as UnityAppController.mm, etc.), but most of the code will be auto-generated and therefore practically impossible to follow. See an example below:

[image: sample xcode]

So all the app's functionality should be developed directly in Unity